# How to record audio in Livecode?

Tags: livecode

I am using `Livecode Community 7.0.4` and I'm trying to create an audio.

I am in `windows 10`.

I created `three` buttons `record`, `stop` and `play`.

And on each button I have these code:

```
//record
on mouseUp
  record sound test.wav
end mouseUp

//stop
on mouseUp
  stop recording
end mouseUp

//play
on mouseUp
  play test.wav
end mouseUp
```

But these are not working. No audio file generated.

What should be the right way to do it?

For the `record`, I also tried this code, but same result.

```
on mouseUp
   set the dontUseQT to false
   record sound test.wav
end mouseUp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you left out the keyword `file`.

```
record sound file "test.wav"
```

Here's the more complete answer. For now, sound recording will only work if you have QuickTime for Windows installed on your system. Be sure to set the recording properties to what you want first. The correct syntax is:

```
set the recordFormat to "wave"
set the recordCompression to "raw " # note trailing space
set the recordSampleSize to 16 # bit depth
set the recordRate to 44.1 # sampling rate
set the dontUseQT to false
record sound file "C:/path/to/file/test.wav"
```

The audio recording framework is being completely rewritten, and will be available sometime in the LC v. 9 series. (Initial alpha releases of v. 9 are out now.) That will remove the QuickTime dependency for audio recording.

Comment: this looks promising but still not working. I'll try to update my QuickTime if there's any miracle :)

Comment: I've found the problem. This is a bug on LC 7.0.4 and this is working fine now after using LC 7.1.4